# NPE while testing for assertEquals

Tags: java, spring, junit5

I am learning Spring from springframeworkguru and we are at testing part. Here is the code he wrote to test a Category class:

```
    class CategoryTest {

    Category category;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        category = new Category();
    }

    @Test
    public void getId() {
        Long idValue = 4L;
        category.setId(idValue);
        assertEquals(idValue, category.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void getDescription() {
    }

    @Test
    public void getRecipes() {
    }
}
```

I know there may happen many changes since he recorded it (he is using junit4 and I use 5), but I get a NullPointerException at assertEquals(idValue, category.getId()); and I have no idea why. Can someone explain it to me step by step (why its not right) and how to fix it?

Comment: It would help if you could show the `Category` class. I can imagine a particular (buggy) implementation that would cause this...

Comment: Are you sure your @Before is called ? Because before is Junit4 and you are saying you are using junit5

Answer (score 3):

Use @BeforeEach instead of @Before in junit5!
And to avoid this problem, remove dependecies to junit vintage if you can, only use junit jupiter, the new gen:

The imports should be:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```